# Element Tree is not modifying element text

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xliff

I am using ElementTree to modify an xliff file with text contained in an Excel sheet. I want to run down the entire file and identify elements where I have a match in my Excel sheet (match is based on segment id which is contained in the "mid" attribute value). Once I find a match, I want to populate the element  with text pulled from the Excel sheet. For this example I am using dummy text "Target Segment{segment id}"

My code does everything I want. I can identify each element and pull the element text and attributes as needed. I set the text value of the element and can see the difference before and after when I print the results - "mrk.text" before is None, and after setting the new value , "mrk.text" is populated with the correct dummy text. So everything looks like it is working correctly.

BUT - when I generate the xml file, I can see the element text is still empty. Meanwhile the other modifications I made to the xml - for example registering namespaces and including the xml declaration are working fine).

I am expecting text to appear in "mrk" elements that are children of "target" elements. But nothing gets written there.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have read through xml.etree.ElementTree documentation on python.org and have searched for the correct answer on this site and several others. I found answers which hint at being the possible solution, but nothing quite does it.

(I know that my tag references can be made without explicitly calling the namespace URIs, but I am new to Element Tree and wanted to solve my problem first before improving my code)

Sample XML that I am trying to modify is here:

```
        <trans-unit id="f60d234c-2d06-47e7-b4aa-e2c7a7caf0e8">
            <source>Please select all that apply.</source>
            <seg-source>
                <mrk mtype="seg"
                     mid="1751">Please select all that apply.</mrk>
            </seg-source>
            <target>
                <mrk mtype="seg"
                     mid="1751"/>
            </target>
        </trans-unit>
```

Relevant python code here:

```
beolroot = ET.parse(filetobeol).getroot()
for tu in beolroot.findall(".//{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}trans-unit"):
    ET.register_namespace("sdl", "http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0")
    ET.register_namespace("", "urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2")
    #print (tu)
    srctxt = tu.find("./{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}source")
    trg = tu.find("./{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}target")
    #print (srctxt)
    print (srctxt.text)
    #print (trg)
    for target in tu.findall("./{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}target"):
        for mrk in target.findall("./{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}mrk"):
            print ("mrk is element id " + str(mrk))
            print ("mrk text is: " +str(mrk.text))
            mid = mrk.get("mid")
            print ("segment id is: " +str(mid))
            if mid in srctrgmap.keys():
                mrk = target.find("./{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}mrk")
                targetvalue = srctrgmap[mid]
                #print(targetvalue)
                mrk.text = str(targetvalue)
                target.text = str(targetvalue)
                print ("mrk is STILL element id: " + str(mrk))
                print ("new mrk text is: " +str(mrk.text))
                print ("new target  text is: " +str(target.text))
            else:
                print("Segment Number " + str(mid) + " has no translation target text")
tree.write("output.sdlxliff", encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

Comment: Namespaces are involved, but the XML sample in the question has no namespaces. That is going to make it harder to help. Please see [mcve].

Comment: Where is `srctrgmap` defined?

Comment: Thank you. I will add more of the xml sample to show the namespaces. srctrgmap is defined in another block of code where it reads an excel file. At the moment it is just a dictionary that has segment id numbers as key and some filler text as value, so it consists of a lot of entries like this {1786 : 'TargetSegment1786,... '}

Comment: OK. But I hope you see the point of a [mcve]. I should be able to copy, paste and run the code in the question without changing anything. That is currently not possible.

Comment: Thank you @mzjn for your help with this. Your suggestion to produce a minimal reproducible example led me to solve the problem. This was my first post on here. I will not forget to do it in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works. As suggested, I worked on a minimal reproducible example. In doing so, I produced a version that worked. I am not certain what was wrong. But this code now does what I need it to do.

Example xml here:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff xmlns:sdl="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0"
       xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"
       version="1.2"
       sdl:version="1.0">
    <file original="C:\File\Location\example.xml">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="a">
                <source>Foo</source>
                <seg-source>
                    <mrk mtype="seg"
                         mid="1328">Foo</mrk>
                </seg-source>
                <target>
                    <mrk mtype="seg"
                         mid="1328"/>
                </target>
                <sdl:seg-defs>Bar</sdl:seg-defs>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="b">
                <source>My Hovercraft</source>
                <seg-source>
                    <mrk mtype="seg"
                         mid="1329">My Hovercraft</mrk>
                </seg-source>
                <target>
                    <mrk mtype="seg"
                         mid="1329"/>
                </target>
                <sdl:seg-defs>Is full of eels</sdl:seg-defs>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="c">
                <source>I will not buy this record</source>
                <seg-source>
                    <mrk mtype="seg"
                         mid="1330">I will not buy this record</mrk>
                </seg-source>
                <target>
                    <mrk mtype="seg"
                         mid="1330"/>
                </target>
                <sdl:seg-defs>It is scratched</sdl:seg-defs>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="d">
                <source>I will not buy this tobacconist</source>
                <seg-source>
                    <mrk mtype="seg"
                         mid="1331">I will not buy this tobacconist</mrk>
                </seg-source>
                <target>
                    <mrk mtype="seg"
                         mid="1331"/>
                </target>
            <sdl:seg-defs>It is scratched</sdl:seg-defs>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="f">
                <source>I want to buy</source>
                <seg-source>
                    <mrk mtype="seg"
                         mid="1332">I want to buy</mrk>
                </seg-source>
                <target>
                    <mrk mtype="seg"
                         mid="1332"/>
                </target>
                <sdl:seg-defs>Some Matches</sdl:seg-defs>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Working python here:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

filetobeol = 'D:\\Stack\\example.xml'

srctrgmap = {'1328': 'Target Segment1328',
             '1330': 'Target Segment1330',
             '1332': 'Target Segment1332'
             }

tree = ET.parse(filetobeol)
beolroot = tree.getroot()
for tu in beolroot.findall(".//{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}trans-unit"):       
    ET.register_namespace("sdl", "http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0")
    ET.register_namespace("", "urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2")
    for target in tu.findall("./{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}target"):
        for mrk in target.findall("./{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}mrk"):
            print ("mrk is element id " + str(mrk))
            print ("mrk text is: " +str(mrk.text))
            mid = mrk.get("mid")
            print ("segment id is: " +str(mid))
            if mid in srctrgmap.keys():
                stillmrk = target.find("./{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}mrk")
                targetvalue = srctrgmap[mid]
                #print(targetvalue)
                stillmrk.text = str(targetvalue)
                print ("mrk is STILL element id: " + str(stillmrk))
                print ("new mrk text is: " +str(stillmrk.text))
            else:
                print("Segment Number " + str(mid) + " has no translation target text")
tree.write("D:\\Stack\\outexample.xml", encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```